# Find value and corresponding entries with number at the end

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with data like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1      A    B   Z-A.P-E-001.02
2      A    B   Z.01
3      A    B   Z.02
4      A    B   Z-A.P-E-001.01
5      C    D   M.01
6      C    D   M.02
```

I want to find values in col4 having numbers at the end (number after last '.'). e.g. in this scenario expected outout is:

```
value col4
Z            Z.01
Z            Z.02
Z            Z.03
M            M.01
M            M.02
Z-A.P-E-001  Z-A.P-E-001.01
Z-A.P-E-001  Z-A.P-E-001.02
```

Can you please give me an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I came to an answer with the help from Melvin Smith:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col4, 0, instr(col4, regexp_substr(col4, '\.\d+$')) -1) AS VALUE, col4
 FROM new_test
  where regexp_like(col4, '\.\d+$');
```

@Melvin: Thanks a ton!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use Orace's regex functions, `regexp_substr()` and `regexp_like()`

I'm not sure what your actual requirements are, but something like this (off top of my head):

```
-- will match up to dot, but not including
select regexp_substr(col4, '^\w+') as value, col4
 from tab
  where regexp_like(col4, '\d');               -- if any digit in column
```

Or if you want to only look for values with numbers at end of field use the $ anchor

```
  where regexp_like(col4, '\d$');
```

Comment: Hello Melvin, Thank you! With example data I had mentioned your logic works fine. But I have added one more sample of complex data. We need to consider such scenarios also. We need to check for string before last '.' character. Please refer to updated question. Thank again for your help.

Comment: @user613114 Use `regexp_like(col4, '\.\d+$')` to keep only values ending with 1 or more digit after the last dot. Regexp are very powerful to deal with that kind of problems. Definitively a skill that has to be mastered ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXP_LIKE` with `DIGIT` character-class and simple `SUBSTR` to only check if the ending character of the string is a `NUMBER` :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 COL1, 'A' COL2, 'B' COL3, 'Z.01' COL4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2,      'P',    'B',   'Z.02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3,      'Q',    'B',   'Z.03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 4,      'C',    'D',   'M.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 5,      'X',    'D',   'M.01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 6,      'C',    'D',   'M.A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 7,      'C',    'D',   'M.1A' FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT * FROM DATA
 10  WHERE regexp_like(substr(col4,-1), '[[:digit:]]')
 11  /

      COL1 C C COL4
---------- - - ----
         1 A B Z.01
         2 P B Z.02
         3 Q B Z.03
         4 C D M.01
         5 X D M.01
         6 C D M.A1

6 rows selected.
```